# Difference between trunk and subscriber line

Tags: telecommunication

Being new to telecommunication, this definition confused me as to what is the difference between a trunk and subscriber line. Please help! :)

[definition of folded and non-folded network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JRbL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Its not a particularly well explained term in that reference, but all it really means is that in a folded network the network  is closed - in other words subscribers can only makes calls to other subscribers of the same network.

A non folded or open network means that subscribers can make calls to people outside the network being discussed.

Its mostly useful as a planning tool.

In real life, most network are not closed or folded for obvious reasons, although local exchanges might be modelled as closed or folded for planning and dimensioning purposes.

Dimensioning in telecoms is very important as telecoms equipment is traditionally expensive so most networks are blocking in one way or another - i.e. they are not engineered to allow every subscriber make a call at the same time as this would be a very rare occurrence and it would be costly to have much of the equipment sitting idle at all other times.

There is a better definition than the one you reference above with some diagrams etc here: http://www.newagepublishers.com/samplechapter/001222.pdf